# Palindrome program - unexpected identifier error

Tags: javascript, palindrome

I am trying to write a JS program to print the largest palindrome between 1 and 1000 (929).  I am getting an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` on line 4 of my code:

```
    var num = 1;

    for (var i=0;i<=1000;i++) {
      if i == reverse(i) && isPrime(i)
          num = i;
          console.log(num);
    }
    document.write(num);

    function reverse(s) {
        var o = '';
        for (var i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            o += s[i];
      return o;
    }

    function isPrime(number) {
        var start = 2;
        while (start <= Math.sqrt(number)) {
            if (number % start++ < 1) return false;
        }
        return number<=1 ? false : true;
    }
```

What is an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`?  And how do I fix the bug?

Comment: `if()` blocks require parens `()` in JavaScript.  `if (i == reverse(i) && isPrime(i)) {`

Comment: Use parentheses and brackets for `if` and `for` like you do with your `while` loop.. and isn't 999 a palindrome?

Comment: As stated above, you're missing parens around your if condition. Don't use shortcut syntax, especially if you're new to a language. Skipping parts of the syntax makes it much harder to see when you've skipped something you shouldn't have.

Comment: ()s work... i guess 999 is a palindrome ;).

Comment: There is still a bug in the logic

Comment: I am looking for the largest PRIME palindrome.  which is 929

Answer (score 3):

> > Your `if` statement is missing parenthesis `()` and block identifiers `{}`.

The syntax for a JavaScript `if` statement is as follows:

```
if (condition) {

    // do something

} else {

    // do something else
}
```

So, change your `if` code above and you should be good!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you missed two brackets inside the for loop but also I think that you have an error in your "reverse" function. Try this solution:

```
var num = 1;

function isReversible(s) {
    var o=s.toString();
    return o.split("").reverse().join("")==s.toString()?true:false;
}

function isPrime(number) {
    var start = 2;
    while (start <= Math.sqrt(number)) {
        if (number % start++ < 1) return false;
    }
    return number<=1 ? false : true;
}

for (var j=0;j<=1000;j++) {
    if (isReversible(j) && isPrime(j))
      num = j;
    console.log(num);
}
document.write(num);
```

Comment: you're missing `{}` in the if block: if(cond) {exec} this will still throw an error

Comment: This code is running in my machine ;). You can skip the brackets {} if you just want to execute the following line inside the if condition. So if(true)console.log("is true"); is the same that if(true){console.log("is true");}

Comment: you're right, it will work but it's bad practice. I'll undo my downvote though